# como almacenar en una variable java una fecha cualquiera y guardarla en mysql

Tags: java, mysql, date

al mandarla a la base de datos me da el siguiente error Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'null' for column 'fechaInscripcion' at row 1
la captura en visita1
String visita1 = request.getParameter("txtVisita1"); y la mando a la base de datos qe es cuando me da el error

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo de lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte?

Comment: public ResultSet getselbyarcodigo(int codigo) throws SQLException
        {
            ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            String sql ="select * from articulo where  ArtCodigo = ?";
            PreparedStatement cm=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            cm.setInt(1, codigo);
            rs=cm.executeQuery();           
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
           throw new SQLException(e) ; 
        } 
        return rs;
    } este es elcodigo del metodo pero al mostralo en el navegador no me muestra las fechas